# How can I replicate SAS 'output' statement functionality in PySpark using Dataframe/SQL operations?

Tags: python, pyspark, sas

I'm working on a tool that tries to automatically convert SAS data statements to Pyspark Dataframe/SQL code. Normally the following type of SAS statement -

```
data output_set;
set input_set;
if cola >= 5 and colb <=9 then do;
   colc="foo";
end;
if cola >= 3 and colb <=7 then do;
   colc="bar";
end;
run;
```

would be converted to something like -

```
output_set = spark.sql("select * from input_set")
output_set = output_set.withColumn('colc', expr("""case when cola >= 5 and colb <=9 then \"foo\" else colc end"""))
output_set = output_set.withColumn('colc', expr("""case when cola >= 3 and colb <=7 then \"bar\" else colc end"""))
```

However, I'm having trouble incorporating handling for the 'output' statement in SAS ([docs here](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n1lltvbis7ye1an1eryo4leh2mck.htm)). Basically, the processing inside SAS data statement is done row-by-row, so whenever an 'output' statement is encountered, SAS writes out the current state of the row to the target dataset.

So if I change the above example to -

```
data output_set;
set input_set;
if cola >= 5 and colb <=9 then do;
   colc="foo";
   output;
end;
if cola >= 3 and colb <=7 then do;
   colc="bar";
   output;
end;
run;
```

Then I can't figure out any Dataframe/SQL conversion for that output statment that would work in the general case. I'm not using RDD operations due to modernity/performance concerns.

If I manually convert this specific example, I was trying using two Dataframes -

```
output_set1 = output_set
output_set1 = output_set1.withColumn('colc', expr("""case when cola >= 5 and colb <=9 then \"foo\" else colc end"""))
output_set2 = output_set
output_set2 = output_set2.withColumn('colc', expr("""case when cola >= 3 and colb <=7 then \"bar\" else colc end""")) 
output_set = output_set1.union(output_set2)
```

However it has two major issues

1. This is not a general case conversion logic of 'output'
2. Union in Pyspark concatenates the Dataframes, but in the source SAS data statement, the output rows would be interleaved.

Comment: A sql query without an `order` clause does not have to following any rules regarding row order.

Comment: SQL doesn't support that type of output statement. You could probably achieve the same using panda's.